# How can I use state to make a POST fetch request on my backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, fetch-api

I'm working on my first app right now which I created in react native for the front end and using Node JS as a backend and MongoDB for the database.
I'm trying to implement register form for my user but I don't really know how to do this with the state because it keeps saying cannot evaluation `this.state.name`.
What I want to do is a POST request using fetch API to register an account it works using Postman so the error come from my front end.

So what I do is I create my function to do that but I want the body to represent the value the user typed in the different field which I store in the state when you'll see the code it will be clear.
If I use the state it does not work however if I put some value directly in my function it works.

This first thing is my function with the fetch API if I do this it does not work, below is how I get the state of each field (see the `<Input>`).

```
clickthebutton = () =>{
    //var data = this.state
    fetch('http://localhost:5050/api/new/register',{
        method:'POST',
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body : {
            name:this.state.name,
            age:this.state.age,
            password:this.state.password,
            email:this.state.email
        },       
    })
}
<Input
                        label="Your email address"
                        placeholder="yo@gmail.com"
                        onChangeText={(text)=> this.setState({email:text})}
                        value={this.state.email}
>
```

My state looks like this :

```
this.state={
            email:null,
            password:null,
            name:null,
            age:null,
            dataImage:null
        }
```

I would like to send the body, if I do body: `this.state` it does not send anything when I do a `console.log(req.body)` on my server it shows an empty object.

EDIT : Problem fixed, my function was not referring to my class.

Comment: Are you sure 'onChangeText' is a built in property for <Input>? Did you mean to use <TextInput> instead? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchangetext

Comment: Hello, yeah looking at the react native element documentation it says so I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified in the header that you send in `json` format when you send. When sending to the server, you must convert to `jsonString`.

```js
fetch('http://localhost:5050/api/new/register', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name:this.state.name,
    age:this.state.age,
    password:this.state.password,
    email:this.state.email
  }),
});
```

Ok You can try use `Formdata`

```js
let formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append("name", this.state.name);
      formdata.append("age", this.state.age);
      formdata.append("password", this.state.password);
      formdata.append("email", this.state.email);
fetch('http://localhost:5050/api/new/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    body: formdata
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(reponse => {
  console.log(reponse)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Hey, yes that's what I did in first but it is not working.

Comment: @Louisnot I am your modification with my answers in comments.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a correct  element for your email and password inputs, for example (for email):

```
<TextInput
    value={this.state.name}
    keyboardType={'email-address'}
    placeholder="Your email address"
    onChangeText={text => this._onEmailChange(text)}
/>
```

you also need a function to update the name value (you will need a similar function to update any value coming from a TextInput element)

```
_onEmailChange = text => {
    this.setState({ name: text });
};
```

Then you can prepare your request as follow

```
fetch('http://localhost:5050/api/new/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: this.state.name,
      password: this.state.password
      ...
    }),
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(responseJson => {
  // do what you want with the response here
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Hello, I am using react native elements for the input, that's why I used Input instead of TextInput but they do the same I also have the function onChange() for updating the state on each field.

Answer (score 0):

After getting all form-data in your state you have two options to make a request to backend.

Either set `Content-Type` As `application/text` or remove `header`.

```
fetch('http://localhost:5050/api/new/register',{
        method:'POST',
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/text'},
        body : {
            name:this.state.name,
            age:this.state.age,
            password:this.state.password,
            email:this.state.email
        },       
    })
```